# Como utilizando botones desde un Fragmen como abrir otros Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

tengo una **clases Frangent** a la que estoy intentando poner botones **ImageButton** para que al escoger uno de ellos muestre otra **clase Fragment**

Este es el código con el que estoy probando ahora, que no hace nada, bueno, al pulsar los iconos la aplicación se cierra.

```
public class Menu_6 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

Button botonRetraso1;
Button botonRetraso2;

private Context context;

public Menu_6() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.menu_6, container, false );

    botonRetraso1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btRetraso1);
    botonRetraso2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btRetraso2);

    botonRetraso1.setOnClickListener(this);
    botonRetraso2.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btRetraso1:
            cargarFragment(new Retrasos1());
            break;

        case R.id.btRetraso2:
            cargarFragment(new Retrasos2());
            break;
    }
}

private void cargarFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}

}
```

Notas:

- He quitado el mensaje de error, porque ahora no muestra ninguno
- He cambiado **ImageButton** por **Button**,   Del código botonRetraso1 =
  (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btRetraso1); he eliminado (Button) parece que es innecesario.

Código de **Retrasos1.java**

```
public class Retrasos1 extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

WebView mWebView;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public Retrasos1() {
}

public static Retrasos newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Retrasos1 fragment = new Retrasos1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString( ARG_PARAM1, param1 );
    args.putString( ARG_PARAM2, param2 );
    fragment.setArguments( args );
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString( ARG_PARAM1 );
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString( ARG_PARAM2 );
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.retrasos1, container, false );

    mWebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView1 );
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );

    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls( false );
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom( WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR );
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort( true );
    mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    mWebView.loadUrl( "https://www.google.es/" );

    return view;
}



public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}
```

**retrasos1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.SoCu.CirDocu.Retrasos1">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Os agradecería si me podéis ayudar con el código para poder *abrir desde un Fragment otros Fragment mediante unos botones*

Un saludo.

Comment: ahi te genera error por que nunca inicializas la variable `context` y dsps le haces un `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Retraso1.class y Retraso2.class son activities o son fragments?

Comment: Hola @armen, son **Fragment**

Comment: Al iniciar la app, te muestra el fragment Menu_6? Así es como inicia, con Menu_6?

Comment: No, tengo un menú horizontal con 9 Fragment, voy haciendo pruebas en cada uno de ellos, y este hace el Fragment 8, en otros tengo puestas paginas web locales, con enlaces que llevan a otras paginas, y funcionan bien.

Comment: No se si tiene que ver algo con lo que me preguntas para que no funcionen los botones al ser pulsado, pero en un futuro si esto se soluciona, hay otros menús que serán iguales, y el Fragment con el que se inicia la aplicación también sea como este del Menu_6.

Comment: @armen he puesto en el `onClick` un botón para abrir una activity y esta si que se muestra, en cambio los botones que tienen que abrir otro Fragment, son los que no se muestran, alguna idea de porque pasa esto, y como se puede solucionar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así como lo tienes es para abrir `Activities`, a partir de un `fragment`, y las Activities deben estar declaradas en el `Manifest`.

Para abrir un `fragment` se utiliza `fragment transaction`, no se necesitan declararlos en el manifest. Y lo mismo se usa para abrir un `fragment`, a partir de una `Activity`. En este caso con un `onClick`:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
        Retraso1 fragment = new Retraso1();  // Retraso1 es el nombre del fragment
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  // si usas import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        //FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();       // si usas import android.app.Fragment;
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "retraso1fragment");    // frame es el id del FrameLayout que va contener los fragments
        ft.addToBackStack(null);                              // para agregarlo a la pila
        ft.commit();
      }
    });
```

En caso de varios botones, con `switch`, es mejor crear un método de transaction:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()){
   case R.id.btRetraso1:
     cargarFragment(new Retraso1());
     break;

   case R.id.btRetraso2:
     cargarFragment(new Retraso2());
     break;
    }
 }

   private void cargarFragment(Fragment fragment) {
      FragmentTransaction ft =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
 }
```

Para abrir una `Activity`, a partir de otra `Activity` se usa `intent`:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityEnLaQueEstas.this, LaOtraActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Si utilizo **import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;** pero me muestra un error, te dejo una captura para mostrar el error. http://funkyimg.com/i/2KPC2.png y el frame del R.id.frame, es el que te muestro tambien en esa captura? te lo pregunto por cambiar el nombre, ya que los otros fragment que llevan los otros botones, también tienen el mismo código.

Comment: Tienes que mostrar los fragments en un container, puede estar en el main_activity o no se como se llame tu activity, o en un app_bar. No debe ir en el webView como dices

Comment: el getSupportFragmentManager() se sigue mostrando en rojo, el XML de la actividad principal se llama activity_main.xml, y ahí tengo puesto android:id="@+id/frame_container" esta es la captura http://funkyimg.com/i/2KPCx.png....

Comment: mira estos son los import http://funkyimg.com/i/2KPCV.png, tengo puesto el **import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;** pero he cambiado el codigo que has puesto por este  http://funkyimg.com/i/2KPCV.png y ha desaparecido el error, como puede ser si no estoy utilizando el **import android.app.Fragment;**

Comment: Si lo tenia puesta así, y me seguía mostrando en rojo, pero lo he borrado todo y al volver a ponerlo ha desaparecido el rojo, pero se queda resaltado en nombre mira la captura http://funkyimg.com/i/2KPEA.png, el caso es que estando así, no funciona, no da error ni pasa nada, pulso sobre los botones y no hace nada,

Comment: respuesta reactualizada, ejemplo con switch. Hay que agregar break;

Comment: Si el codgio que pones es mas claro, y mucho mas cuando va a llevar unos cuantos botones, pero llevo toda la mañana probando y buscando algún error, y sigue sin mostrar nada cuando se pulsar el botón, como si el botón no estuviese activado, he cambiado el código de arriba y he añadido el Fragment Retrasos y el xml, por si el error se encontrase ahí.

Comment: no entiendo porque no funciona si tengo puesto el mismo código, la única diferencia que he visto entre el primer código y el segundo método que pones para crear la transición es que **"retraso1fragment"** no está en ese código, o hay que tener en el build.gradle alguna configuración ? o se puede ver algo en el **Logcat**, cuando pulso sobre uno de los botones se crea esta línea **08-31 16:43:06.892 11296-11353/com.SoCu.CirDocu E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ff** la pongo por si alguien sabe que quiere decir.

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta que tu atributo context esta en null

```
Intent detail = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Retraso1.class);
context.startActivity(detail);
```

Porque no pruebas de esta forma

```
Intent detail = new Intent(getActivity(), Retraso1.class);
getActivity().startActivity(detail);
```

Comment: @Julian no ignoro tu comentario, pero no tengo muy claro como hacer lo que comentas, y al poner Kenji el código he probado con este, he cambiado el código y me sigue mostrando error al pulsar el botón, voy a modificar el primer post con este código y el mensaje de error, que dejo la primera linea que muestra el error, porque no entiendo muy bien, pero es que hay que declarar los Fragment en el **AndroidManifest.xml**

Comment: Los fragment no son necesarios declararlos en el AndroidManifest.xml, en este caso al que debes declarar es a la clase Retrasos.class; 

<activity
       android:name=".Retrasos"
        android:label="@string/title" />

Comment: Si he intento ponerlo antes de poner mi comentario, pero la clase Ratrasos es otro Fragmen, **public class Retrasos extends Fragment {*  lo que muestro en este Fragmen Retrasos es una pagina web, y en otros botones mostrare un archivo PDF, pero eso ya es otro problema, primero intento solucionar este, por eso he comentado que intento abrir un desde Fragment otro Frangment.

Comment: Ahora estoy en un **Fragment** y con el `onClick` abro otro Fragment, como podía hacer para que desde éste onClick pueda abrir una Activity ? estoy introduciendo el código, pero como en el caso anterior no hace nada al pulsar los botones, y parece que cuando pongo un código que no es correcto sí que se produce un error al pulsar los botones.

Answer (score 1):

Hola para pasar de un Fragmento a otro es diferente que de una clase a otra.

```
botonRetraso1 .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Retraso1= new Frg_Retraso1 ();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_main, Retraso1);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

** y en la parte superior llama al Fragmento que te quieres comunicar:
**Frg_Retraso1  Retraso1;**

** En el R.id.content_main siempre va a apuntar a tu Main, por que es la principal, asi es que a tu XML de tu Main principal ponle un ID asi **android:id="@+id/content_main**", y listo

Y otra cosita no te recomiendo usar un Imagen Button usa un boton normal, le puedes añadir una imagen igual, es mucho más facil.

Comment: Gracias Bloom, mañana intento cambiarlo por un botón normal, pense para redireccionar las imágenes dentro del boton se conseguirá en Image Botton

Comment: porque no recomiendas usar Imagen Button?

Comment: Cuando utilice el imagenButton, no me llamaba a nada, por más que el codigo estaba bien y al cambiarlo por un Button normal, le agregue la imagen y todo funciona OK

Comment: Ok, aquí por desgracia ni con Button ni imagenButton llama a nada, porque al pulsar los botones no hace nada, ni muestra un error por el que te pueda dar información de que esta mal

Comment: hazle un seguimiento  desde que declaras tu botón, hasta donde le das la función para que ejecute, ponle: System.out.println("11111111"); y así sucesivamente... y en tu RUN verificas, hasta que número llega, ahí te das cuenta del problema

Comment: Como pongo en la imagen, está en una clase Fragment, hay dos botones, uno llama a una clase Activity que este botón si funciona, y el otro llama a una clase Fragment, donde el botón no funciona, he puesto System.out.println("11111111"); que parece que tiene que mostrar el resultado por pantalla, y no muestra nada, http://funkyimg.com/i/2LBt9.png

Comment: pásame tu código, si lo puedo resolver, por que al principio tambien tenía yo problemas parecidos a los tuyos. michelle_alvarez.20@hotmail.com

Comment: Gracias Bloom, estoy fuera, cuando llegue esta noche a casa te lo mando.

Comment: solo es para decirte que ya te envié el correo, no se si te ha llegado, en él te decía que si lo recibías me dijeses algo para ver que te llego, al ver que no comentas si te ha llegado por si lo estas esperando, solo es para decirte si te lo envíe ese mismo día

Comment: Hola SoCu, si me llego, lo revisare mañana y ni bien lo tengo te lo envío